# Error 1041 "Out Of Memory" after pointing tmpdir to new disk space

Tags: mysql, index, memory

I want to index a very large column in a very large table. The default `/tmp` does not have enough disk space and is throwing [no space left on device error](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/02/25/mysql-error-1034-incorrect-key-file-on-innodb-table/).

I have a much larger filesystem partitioned where I can point `innodb_tmpdir` to.

- I created a tmp dir in this partition: `/mnt/partition/tmp`
- Changed the permissions of this directory to 777 `chmod -R 777 /mnt/partition/tmp`
- Then I set the `innodb_tmpdir` variable to point to this directory via mysql client: `SET VARIABLE innodb_tmpdir='/mnt/partition/tmp';`
- The variable is set correctly by executing: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_tmpdir';`

The issue arises when I try to create an index with the following basic command structure:

```
create index a on b (c, d, e, f);
```

The following error is instantly thrown:

> ERROR 1041 (HY000): Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space

What is with this error? Do I need to set some permissions/configs for my partition?

**NOTE** If I do not set `innodb_tmpdir` and keep everything to default, the index command runs without this issue. (obviously it crashes halfway through due to the limited disk space which is the actual reason why I am changing tmpdir

**my.cnf**

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
wait_timeout=604800
interactive_timeout=604800
local_infile=ON
binlog_expire_logs_seconds=600
skip-log-bin
```

**swap size:** 8.39GB. There is 7GB of memory on the server.

MYSQL Version 8 on Ubuntu 18.04. Machine is fully dedicated to MySQL.

After executing the create index command on new innodb_tmpdir `error.log` file is showing:

```
[ERROR] [MY-012792] [InnoDB] Cannot create temporary merge file
```

Answer (score 2):

If `innodb_tmpdir` being set to the new location is causing an instant complaint from the server, there's a very good chance that `apparmor` is preventing MySQL from accessing the location or that the system is reacting to the `777` permissions, which are often rejected by a lot of server applications for obvious reasons. You will need to check your `error.log` file to see whether the `innodb_tmpdir` location is being used.

---

`apparmor` fixes are quite easy to fix [from Oracle a blog a long time ago](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/apparmor-and-mysql-v2):

> If you want to relocate the data directory in MySQL (in this example, to the /`data/` directory), and AppArmor is not letting you, add the following two lines to the bottom of `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld`:
>
> ```
> /data/ r,
> /data/** rwk,
> ```
>
> ...and then reload the AppArmor profiles:
>
> ```
> # service apparmor reload
> ```